# How to raise the button command event from JavaScript ?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

How can we fire the button command event from the JavaScript.

Not the BUTTON onclick event.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1775788/asp-net-dynamic-command-button-event-not-firing ?

Comment: @Venkat Baggu: Could you please clarify the question with an example?

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery:

```
$("#button").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //Actions here
});
```

`#button` is the id of the button