# Dynamically added ASP.NET button click handler being ignored

Tags: c#, asp.net, events

I am adding event handlers to a button like this:

```
btn.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);
```

However the `btn_Click` function is not being called (never hits the breakpoint in it) and the button just reloads the page. In my past experience, asp buttons usually perform the click code before reloading the page, so how do I get that to happen when the event is dynamically added?

I also set `CausesValidation = false`, although there's no validation on the page so I don't think that would have influence anyway.

Comment: Which event do you have that code?

Comment: Check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1775788/asp-net-dynamic-command-button-event-not-firing

Comment: You have to add this code in in Page.Load and not in page.IsPostback? Is this the mistake you are making ?

Comment: OK I think I get it. I was adding it during another button click, but I need to add it during page load instead for it to work...am I understanding correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The event handler needs to be bound for every request regardless of whether or not the page is being posted back. The binding of the event handler is lost at the start of each page request. Event handlers for buttons are typically bound in Page_Load.

Comment: Both of these answers help me to understand, although I can only accept one. Either way, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have to set event handlers on `Load` event (or before). If you do it after `Load`, it won't be executed since by the time the handler for the event is evaluated it won't be there.

Check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) msdn article in relation to page life cycle. I think it will help you to understand. See that event handling occurs inmediatly after `Load`