# Cannot capture button onclick event on usercontrol

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, events, user-controls, raiseevent

Its been 4 hours since i thought "How can i trigger my event from a usercontrol's button click?" and the answer came very fast : "i can caputre the button's click event and raise mine from there!" and after 4 hours of debugging and debugging and more debugging and page lifecycle and more debugging and more breakpoints and so on and so forth i turn for help to the GREAT STACKOVERFLOW(bows). So the question is quite straightforward; Why cant i capture the onclick event of a button placed inside a usercontrol so i can trigger my event? 
As for the code :
Here is the ascx :

```
<%@ Control Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="CosmaButton.ascx.vb" Inherits="Comanda.CosmaButton" %>
```

Code behind for the usercontrol :

```
Public Class CosmaButton
Inherits System.Web.UI.UserControl

Public Event ClickBtn As EventHandler

Private _title As String = "test"
Private _width As Integer
Private WithEvents _button As New Button

Protected Overrides Sub OnInit(e As EventArgs)
    MyBase.OnInit(e)
End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub OnLoad(e As EventArgs)
    MyBase.OnLoad(e)
End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub OnPreRender(e As EventArgs)
    _button.CssClass = "styled"
    _button.Text = _title
    _button.Attributes("runat") = "server"
    If _width > 0 Then
        _button.Width = _width
    End If
    Me.Controls.Add(_button)
    MyBase.OnPreRender(e)
End Sub

Protected Sub _button_Clicked(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    RaiseEvent ClickBtn(Nothing, Nothing)

End Sub

End Class
```

and finally here is the codebehind for the aspx page:

```
Public Class Login1
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub Page_Init(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Init

End Sub

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    AddHandler btn.ClickBtn, AddressOf btn_Click
End Sub

Protected Sub btn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn.ClickBtn

End Sub

End Class
```

PS did my homework and searched every post that related to this isssue and found :
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33874/Capture-Button-s-Click-Event-of-User-Control-in-th
which is kind of frustrating because i followed and refollowed and went step by step in this guy's post but the same effect. No freaking clickevent!

EDIT 1:

added handler to click event so the updated codebehind version is the following:

```
Public Class CosmaButton
Inherits System.Web.UI.UserControl

Public Event ClickBtn As EventHandler

Private _title As String = "test"
Private _width As Integer
Private WithEvents _button As New Button

Protected Overrides Sub OnInit(e As EventArgs)
    Me.Controls.Add(_button)

    AddHandler _button.Click, AddressOf _button_Clicked

    MyBase.OnInit(e)
End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub OnLoad(e As EventArgs)
    MyBase.OnLoad(e)
End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub OnPreRender(e As EventArgs)
    _button.CssClass = "styled"
    _button.Text = _title
    _button.Attributes("runat") = "server"
    If _width > 0 Then
        _button.Width = _width
    End If
    MyBase.OnPreRender(e)
End Sub

Protected Sub _button_Clicked(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    RaiseEvent ClickBtn(Nothing, Nothing)

End Sub


End Class
```

and still nothing.
I added the handler many times before but after reading and trying the post up mentioned, i added an asp:button tag to my usercontrol but with no success, and after that i posted the question.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly (with my not so good knowledge of VB.net) you are dynamically adding a button to your user control. But the button click event is never bound. If you just add a handler for button click event on your user control, things would probably work for you.

Another piece of advice when ever playing with dynamic controls always try to add control on `page init` or `preinit` so you can make use of the advantages of `viewstate`.

Edit 1:

I have created a sample for you, that would help you solve the issue. For your user control you can place the button in designer itself (here is what I did):
**[User Control Designer]**

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="button" />
```

Now on the code behind of the user control, I added the following code:
**[User Control Code Behind]**

```
Public Event AnEvent()

Protected Sub button_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles button.Click
        RaiseEvent AnEvent()
End Sub
```

botton_Click is the click event of the button added on your user control. The click of this button raises AnEvent. Now this makes your user control a full package having it's own event.

The only thing left to do is add this user control to your page and handle the AnEvent. The following two  lines on the page added the user control and handeled the event for me:
**[Web Page Designer (Adding user control)]**

```
<%@ Register src="WebUserControl1.ascx" tagname="WebUserControl1" tagprefix="uc1" %>

<uc1:WebUserControl1 ID="WebUserControl11" runat="server" OnAnEvent="WebUserControl11_AnEvent"  />
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: i added the handler, but still nothing, it never hits the breakpoint on click.See my edit :(

Comment: Did you try moving you button definition from pre render to page init.

Comment: What do you mean with move the button definition? Can you give me an example? If you mean to call the Page.Controls.Add method on another event than the answer is yes... i have tried init to prerender otherwise if you can be more specific that would be very usefull. Thank a lot!

Comment: I have updated my answer. I have tested the code as well and its working fine.

Comment: Thanks, i created another project, tried this and it works like a charm, however on my project it still does not work :(, but now i know that the issue is somewhere else. Thank you for your time and patience with me. I wish you very much success in everything that you are doing!

Answer (score 1):

Shashank's right. Here somebody wrote something similar

[ASP.NET dynamic Command Button event not firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1775788/asp-net-dynamic-command-button-event-not-firing)

Apparently, your code lacks the instruction

```
AddHandler _button.Click, AddressOf btn_Click
```

to add a handler for button click, and remove

```
Protected Sub _button_Clicked(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    RaiseEvent ClickBtn(Nothing, Nothing)
End Sub
```

Comment: Before writing this post i have added the handler and after that i added the button into my ascx page(with tags) and handled the binding there but with no effect. Sorry if that was confusing. Thanks a lot!